# Pullbacks in the Ind-completion

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a category $\mathcal{C}$, say finitely complete. Does the $\text{Ind}$-completion $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ (which informally is the completion of $\mathcal{C}$ under filtered colimits -- see [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object) for a precise construction) have pullbacks? Can these be described (relatively) concretely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{C}$ has finite limits then $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ has finite limits. (However, the converse is false.)

Indeed, let $\mathcal{J}$ be a finite diagram. By hypothesis, there is an adjunction
$$\Delta \dashv \varprojlim : [\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}] \to \mathcal{C}$$
where $\Delta : \mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}]$ sends each object in $\mathcal{C}$ to the corresponding constant diagram of shape $\mathcal{J}$. Thus, there is an induced adjunction
$$\mathbf{Ind}(\Delta) \dashv \mathbf{Ind}(\varprojlim) : \mathbf{Ind}([\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}]) \to \mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$$
and by using the fact that filtered colimits preserve finite limits in $\mathbf{Set}$, it can be shown that the canonical functor
$$\mathbf{Ind}([\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}]) \to [\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})]$$
is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects. Thus, $\Delta : \mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C}) \to [\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})]$ has a right adjoint, i.e. $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ has limits for diagrams of shape $\mathcal{J}$.

Unfortunately, it is not easy to give a concrete description of finite limits in $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ – the hard part is in describing the equivalence $\mathbf{Ind}([\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C}]) \to [\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})]$ explicitly.

Comment: It also follows from the fact that Ind(C) is a reflective subcategory of presheaves on C, where limits are computed object-wise, right?

Comment: Does that mean in particular that the limits in Ind(C) agree with those in PSh(C)? That would go a long way for me as far as concreteness goes.

Comment: @AdeelKhan No. First you would need to know that $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ is reflective and secondly you would need to know that the reflector preserves finite limits. The first doesn't always happen and I don't know whether the second ever happens.

Comment: @MeesdeVries It is true that the canonical fully faithful embeding $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathbf{Psh}(\mathcal{C})$ preserves filtered colimits and all limits. But that doesn't tell you which limits exist or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift response and clarification; you've helped me out a great deal!

Comment: @ZhenLin, sure, there may be set-theoretic obstacles to Ind(C) being reflective.  But if it is reflective, isn't the inclusion monadic, and therefore creates all limits that exist in the target?

Comment: @AdeelKhan It's not a set-theoretic obstacle. $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ is reflective in $\mathbf{Psh}(\mathcal{C})$ if and only if it is cocomplete, but that doesn't always happen.

Comment: @ZhenLin, could you perhaps give a little more detail (or a reference) on how to prove essential surjectivity of $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{[J,C]}) \to [\mathcal{J},\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})]$?

Comment: Well, we don't really need that in full generality – it would be enough to know it for $\mathcal{J} = \emptyset$ and $\mathcal{J} = \{ \bullet \rightarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet \}$; the former is easy and the latter can be done by hand.

Comment: I got that far; doing the case where $\mathcal{J}$ is the cospan category "by hand'' is precisely where I get stuck.

Comment: The claim implies that $[\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})]$ is a finitely accessible category where the finitely presentable objects are the diagrams whose vertices are finitely presentable. You have to express every diagram as a filtered colimits of such diagrams – but in fact you just have to check that the canonical diagram whose vertices are all finitely presented diagrams works.